# Embed PDF Viewer with annotation like highlight, scribble, add note using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-annotations

I have a website build on CakePHP framework. I have already integrated Dompdf library for generating PDF from HTML.

And now for viewing the PDF files, I need a pdf reader that will be embedded into the website with limited capabilities so that the files cannot be printed or shared. Ideally, this would be the layout of the reader. The top would show the title of the document and people can highlight, scribble, add note to the document.

Comment: https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter

Answer (score 1):

Please try out [PdfJs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/)

It suits your needs the most and it has good documentation so you could get started quickly

Comment: PDF.js is mainly written for reading PDF files, not editing them. Because of that they don't yet support adding any kind of annotations.

Comment: This worked out fine for me. [Annotation layer for pdf.js](https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js)

Comment: you need to create your own. you can check out this video [Create annotations in PDF.JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2YAn-Yvlss)

Comment: This video points to a someone who is selling what he did and not trying to explain how it's done.